# SQL: outer join two tables on String and insert similar into another

Tags: sql, outer-join

I have two tables A and B with 30 columns (same variable names, data for different year), no primary key, almost a million records each.

I want to compare `A.X1` with `B.X1` (`nvarchar8`, contains spaces, -, letter and numbers) and insert the outer join results in another table C (with same 30 columns) so I have all rows of A and where B!=A on B.X1).

Example:

Table A

```
X1   X2   X3 ..... X30
11   E     R .....  G
12   R     4        L
13  S      5        NULL   
14  D      T        NULL
```

Table B

```
X1   X2   X3 ..... X30
11   E     R .....  G
12   R     4        L
15  R2     56        NULL   
16  R1      T1        NULL
```

Resulting table C

```
X1   X2   X3 ..... X30
11   E     R .....  G
12   R     4        L
13  S      5        NULL   
14  D      T        NULL
15  R2     56        NULL   
16  R1      T1        NULL
```

How do I do that.

I tried

```
INSERT INTO C
SELECT *
from A
full outer join B
on A.X1 = B.X1
```

Error I get

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I have C created, which is currently empty.

Comment: It seems all you need is UNION of A and B.

Comment: Rather than SELECT * you should specify the column names.

Comment: And you should also always specify the column on the `INSERT` clause to avoid any surprises and problems!

Answer (score 1):

```
insert  C
select  *
from    A
union all
select  *
from    B
where  not exists
       (
       select  *
       from    A
       where   X1 = B.X1
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query will not work becasue you are joining the tables and retunring *, with ill results in twice the number of columns that you need.
What you really want to do is select everything from table A then APPEND (rather than join) all the records from table B.
Appends are achieved by using a UNION. Here is some sample code. Note: never, ever use SELECT *. Addapt the follwing to include the specifically named fields in the correct order.

Also, I am using UNION rather than UNION ALL so that the query automaticlly excludes the records in B that are duplicates of records in A.

```
SELECT FIELDS...
FROM TABLEA
UNION
SELECT SAME_FIELDS...
FROM TABLEB
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Insert Into TableC
(
  -- List your fields explicitly
)
Select
    -- List all tableA.Fields explicitly
From tableA
Left Outer Join tableB On tableB.X1 = tableA.X1
Where tablB.X1 IS NULL
```

Comment: An outer join between A and B will result in a table of 60 columns width.  C has just 30 columns.

Comment: That's why I said "List all tableA.Fields explicitly". Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: This kind of operation requires a union, not a join.  You're missing the point.  And it's not my downvote.